# Using FIND and IF EXIST to delete a specific phrase from a text file

Tags: windows, command-line, find

I am trying to trim a text file, although I have used the following command with no luck:

```
FIND "word1" C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.txt | IF EXIST "word1" (DEL "word1")
```

The syntax is incorrect, I have tried many different combination with no luck.

Comment: `IF EXIST` and `DEL` are commands that work on files, not text within a file.

Comment: That's disappointing :(, I wonder if there is an alternative method

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you are wanting to do?  The given (invalid) command is not clear, at least to me.  Are you trying to remove a specific chunk of text (e.g., "word1") from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove specific text from a file, you can use sed (there are versions available for Windows [such as this one](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)).  For example, to remove all instances of "word1":

```
sed -e "s/word1//g" inputfile > outputfile
```

Or if you want to only remove "word1" when it is not embedded in other text:

```
sed -e "s/\bword1\b//g" inputfile > outputfile
```

The second one uses `\b` to indicate word boundaries.  Note that in a Windows command prompt, you need to enclose the sed script in double quotes.